# SSRS STUFF() USING XML PATH ISSUE

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SQL query the uses `STUFF()` with `XML PATH` syntax to combine multiple rows of clients in one row based on the parent client.

It should only combine Clients under the Parent Client, but what is happening when I run the script is that it is combining all clients in one row regardless of the Parent Client.

For example:

> Parent Client: ABC Company
>
> Client: D Inc, C Inc, F Inc

```
(CASE WHEN PGType='COS' THEN STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Client FROM #Resulttbl r
            WHERE ParentClient = r.[ParentClient]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') 
            ELSE Client END)
```

Comment: Without knowing your data it almost seems like its not getting any matches so it moves on to your else clause.

Comment: I figured it out. im missing additional report filter WHERE PGTYPE='COS'. thanks.

Comment: Good to hear, Can you answer it and mark it answered so it gets resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added additional filter `WHERE PGTYPE='COS'`